# Core Data Concurrency with parent/child relationship and NSInvocationOperation done right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, concurrency

I've been using Core Data to store iOS app data in a SQLite DB. Data is also synchronized to a central server during login or after `n` minutes have passed and as the app grew, synchronization got slower and needed a background process to prevent freezing of the main thread.

For this I rewrote my Synchronization class to use `NSInvocationOperation` class for each process in the synchronization method. I'm using dependencies as the data being imported/synchronized has several dependent relationships.

Then I add all operations into an `NSOperationQueue` and let it run.

There are two additional important elements:

1. When I generate the operations to execute I also create a new UUID NSString, which represents a synchronization ID. This is used to track which Entities in Core Data have been synchronized, therefore, every Entity has an attribute that stores this synchronization ID. It is only used during the synchronization process and is accesses by each method passed to `NSInvocationOperation`.
2. The import and synchronization methods are the actual methods that access Core Data. Inside each of those methods I create a new instance of `NSManagedObjectContext` as follows:

   ```
   PHAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   NSManagedObjectContext *privateContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
   [privateContext setParentContext:[appDelegate mainManagedObjectContext]];
   ```

   using `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` as opposed to `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` which is used in the AppDelegate for the main MOC. Then I create the parent/child relationship using the MOC from the main thread and that's that. When saving the child MOC, I understand that changes propagate back to the main MOC and to the store (SQLite).

I'm fairly new to concurrency in iOS and used this to guide me: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-concurrency--cms-22131 (see Strategy #2). **Different from this article and many other sources that I've seen, I do not subclass NSOperation**. Instead, my approach uses NSInvocationOperation in order to pass each method that I want to run concurrently.

**My question**: Can you take a look at my code and see if you find something that I'm doing wrong or do you think that this will work? So far, I've had no problems running the code. But concurrency is tough to debug, so before we ship this code, I'd like to have more experienced eyes on this.

Thanks in advance!

Synchronization class code on pastebin.com: http://pastebin.com/CUzWw4Tv
(not everything is in the code paste, but it should be enough to evaluate the process, let me know if you need more)

Comment: Lines 140-150 on your pastebin link are you adding those dependencies just to avoid concurrency in the `managedObjectContext` or do they need to go in that order?

Comment: @Drmorgan these are the only operations out of the bunch that need to be in that order since the import/synchronization has certain relations in the core data SQLite DB structure.